# How should I encrypt Ubuntu Server 14.04 with AES on RAID 10 and RAID 5?

Tags: server, partitioning, encryption, performance, raid

After researching I've come to the conclusion that my set up is just not standard enough to have a direct answer floating about on the interwebs.

My Hardware:

- i7 950 CPU
- 24 GB DDR3
- 7 2TB 7200 RPM HDDs

My Goals:

- Fast, light-weight, secure server to run CPU/memory intensive programs (basically run server at 80% continuously)
- Large storage space for movies, TV, whatever else
- Host a few VMs (lets say 3 ubuntu desktop 14.04)
- system firewall (leaning towards ufw) in addition to external HW FW
- Encrypt all 7 disks
- require a USB drive and password to access drives and boot the Ubuntu 14.04 server

Software RAID Partitions:

- md0 300GB Software RAID 10
- md1 9.5TB Software RAID 5

Each disk's partitions:

- 100GB Software RAID 10
- 1.9TB Software RAID 5
- 10GB swap

I understand the Ubuntu Live installer uses dm-crypt with the option of AES.  How much will this affect my performance?  Is it worth not encrypting the RAID 5 array for storage, where encryption is not as important?  How can I require a USB drive with a private key to boot the system, in addition to a passphrase?  I'd like the USB drive to be required just to boot the system, and be removed if the system is in-use.  Is there a way to use stronger encryption?

As far as I can tell, [AES is the best option for performance](http://panthema.net/2008/0714-cryptography-speedtest-comparison/).

*How should I proceed to encrypt Ubuntu Server 14.04 with AES on RAID 10 and RAID 5 using the above parameters?*

Comment: "The best" is an opinion and off-topic here.  "How to" is allowed.  Re-editing again and seeing whether I can come up with an answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between "partitions" and "each disk"?  Do you want each disk to have a 10GB swap and stripe that?  Should the USB key only be used to boot or be in there all the time as long as drives are reading/writing?  I'm assuming you *will* be using hardware RAID and you *will* be wanting encrypted back-ups as well...

Comment: Thank you for your update and questions.  I've edited and hope my post is clearer.  No RAID on the 10GB swap partitions.  Software RAID and no backups because it's in a RAID (at least I don't think I need them with encryption).  The installer says I need a /boot partition for encryption, but I did not set that up before committing changes and creating md0_crypt and md1_crypt...so I'm currently stuck and will have to add another partition for RAID 10 /boot for encryption I think.

Answer (score 1):

- **Software RAID: *Don't do it!***

  I've never ever in my entire career seen a software RAID actually *gracefully* recover from damaged hardware, whereas I've seen tons of software RAIDs <strike>crap out</strike> create problems when there were no hardware problems at all...
- **Back-up:**

  RAID is a protection against a single disk failure (or dual disk failure in case of RAID-6)!  It is *not* a replacement for back-ups!

  Make monthly system back-ups using CloneZilla, and weekly file back-ups using whatever software you like.  Don't encrypt the back-ups unless the encryption is purely password-hash-based as an encrypted back-up encrypted by keys is unrestorable if you lose the keys...

  Make regular back-ups of the USB key you're going to use to boot the system (e.g. at system shutdown) and use an [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) USB stick (4GB should be plenty) and not an [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) one.
- **Software encryption:**

  On top of hardware RAID, I'm advising you to take a decent hardware encryption granddaughter-board on top of your Hardware RAID daughter board.

That is my recommendation for your use case...

Comment: I've used the software RAID for a few years; it has worked for me.  Without discussing too many details, what I need backed up will be on another physical device.

Answer (score 0):

For using a keyfile in addition to a passphrase, this link should help (though I haven't tried these instructions myself):
https://www.finnie.org/2009/07/26/keyfile-based-luks-encryption-in-debian/

The CPU impact of FDE with LUKS is negligible, especially since you have an i7 which comes with built-in AES optimization. Unless you are trying to squeeze the last 2% of processing power out of your server, it will not be an issue. Your IO speed will always be the bottleneck, not AES. As comparison, your filesystem mounting options like atime or enabling/disable drive sleep will make much more of a performance impact in every use case.

Edit: Also, I actually *suggest* software raid. Hardware RAID is great until your RAID card goes out and you have to figure out how to extract the data or rebuild it, which involves sourcing an exact duplicate model of your card (which will likely take days with shipping). And whether or not you can just plug in the drives and go depends on what options the card provides. Hardware RAID can increase performance significantly vs software RAID, but it can be a headache when it fails. Software RAID is also much easier to manage in most situations.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...